# Como posso converter valores .Row para string e inserir numa combobox? C#

Tags: c#

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
for(int i = 1; i<dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{comboBox.Items.Add( dataTable.Rows[i].ToString());}
```

Quando executo a aplicação, na `combobox` apenas me aparece `System.Data.DataRow`.
Queria que me aparecessem todos os itens da tabela no `combobox`.

Comment: Não seria isso: `dataTable.Rows[i]["nome_da_coluna"].ToString()` ?

Comment: Obrigado, que coisa parva XD

Comment: Estou votando para fechar pois a pergunta foi respondida nos comentários e já se passam dois anos sem que uma resposta fora postada.